# How to reset IEnumerator variable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I have a movement coroutine in my code (that moves 1 unit of distance per second).

```
public IEnumerator Move(int distance){...}
```

I have a list of `IEnumerator`s that are basically calls of this coroutine:

```
public List<IEnumerator> routines = new List<IEnumerator>();

void Start(){ routines.Add(Move(1)); routines.Add(Move(-1)); }
```

I want my object to keep moving forward and backwards forever, so I tried this:

```
public IEnumerator LoopMovement(){
    while(true){
        StartCoroutine(routines[0]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        StartCoroutine(routines[1]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

It works fine in the first loop, but after this, it doesn't do anything. I guess it's because the `IEnumerator` variables in the list `routines` have already done their job and won't repeat when called again. How can I reset the `IEnumerator` variable so when I call it again it does what it is supposed to?

Comment: You could make a queue of commands, and while there is an item, do it, else just wait another second.. etc.. but this doesnt seem like a good way to do this

Answer (score 4):

Don't add coroutine calls to an array like that. It doesn't do what you want it to do.

This should work instead:

```
public IEnumerator LoopMovement(){
    while(true){
        yield return Move(1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        yield return Move(-1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

Now, if you wanted to set up a list of actions such that you could modify the *list* without having to modify `LoopMovement`, then you'd have to create a list of *delegates* (aka method references, below uses [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8)s) not pointers to yield statements (kinda-sorta what `IEnumerator` is for coroutines).

Something like this:

```
public List<Func<int,IEnumerator>> routines = new List<Func<int,IEnumerator>>();
routines.Add(Move);
routines.Add(Move);
```

..and..

```
public IEnumerator LoopMovement(){
    while(true){
        yield return routines[0](1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        yield return routines[1](-1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

You will have to consider how you want to [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) your movement methods so that you can have a consistent set of parameters and may need to involve several levels of [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: My question, matter of fact, is just a fraction of my problem. I have a lot of `IEnumerator`s like `Move`, such as `Jump`, `Shoot`, `Fly`, etc., each one with their own parameters and other stuff. The list `routines` stores a lot of these and that's why I'm doing the way I shown and I needed a way to reset the `IEnumerator` vars.

Comment: You can't, though. The only way to "reset" it is to call `Move(1)`. There's no way to do what you're asking. You need to restructure.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when caching the [IEnumerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-8.0) in a list or array and looping through them. It doesn't restart even when trying the [Reset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset?view=net-8.0#system-collections-ienumerator-reset) method from the docs, resulting in an error.

*CODE EXAMPLE (before):*

```
public List<IEnumerator> routines = new List<IEnumerator>();
int routineIndex;

Coroutine routineLoop;

void Start()
{
    routines.Add(Routine1());
    routines.Add(Routine2());
    routines.Add(Routine3());
    routines.Add(Routine4());
    routines.Add(Routine5());
    
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

void StartRoutineLoop()
{
    if(routineLoop != null)
        StopCoroutine(routineLoop);
    
    routineLoop = StartCoroutine(InvokeRoutineLoop());
}

IEnumerator InvokeRoutineLoop()
{
    for(; routineIndex < routines.Count; routineIndex ++)
    {
        yield return routines[routineIndex];
    }
}

// The problem occurs when stopping the coroutine and starting it again
[ContextMenu("Previous")]
public void PreviousRoutine()
{
    routineIndex --;
    routineIndex = Mathf.Clamp(routineIndex, 0, routines.Count);
    
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

[ContextMenu("Next")]
public void NextRoutine()
{
    routineIndex ++;
    routineIndex = Mathf.Clamp(routineIndex, 0, routines.Count);
    
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

#region ROUTINES

    IEnumerator Routine1()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 1 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 1 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine2()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 2 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 2 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine3()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 3 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 3 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine4()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 4 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 4 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine5()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 5 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 5 Exited");
    }

#endregion
```

So, what I did was implement a *workaround* using a **SWITCH** instead.

*CODE EXAMPLE (after):*

```
int routineIndex;
Coroutine routineLoop;

void Start()
{
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

void StartRoutineLoop()
{
    if(routineLoop != null)
        StopCoroutine(routineLoop);
    
    routineLoop = StartCoroutine(InvokeRoutineLoop());
}

// Rather than caching the IEnumerators in a variable, just call them directly instead
IEnumerator InvokeRoutineLoop()
{
    while(routineIndex < 5)
    {
        switch(routineIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                yield return Routine1();
                break;
            
            case 1:
                yield return Routine2();
                break;
            
            case 2:
                yield return Routine3();
                break;
            
            case 3:
                yield return Routine4();
                break;
            
            case 4:
                yield return Routine5();
                break;
            
        }
        
        routineIndex ++;
    }
}

[ContextMenu("Previous")]
public void PreviousRoutine()
{
    routineIndex --;
    routineIndex = Mathf.Clamp(routineIndex, 0, routines.Count);
    
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

[ContextMenu("Next")]
public void NextRoutine()
{
    routineIndex ++;
    routineIndex = Mathf.Clamp(routineIndex, 0, routines.Count);
    
    StartRoutineLoop();
}

#region ROUTINES

    IEnumerator Routine1()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 1 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 1 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine2()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 2 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 2 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine3()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 3 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 3 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine4()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 4 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 4 Exited");
    }

    IEnumerator Routine5()
    {
        Debug.Log("Routine 5 Entered");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Debug.Log("Routine 5 Exited");
    }

#endregion
```